# Margins or paddings when it comes to inner-div spacing?

Tags: css

Here's what I'm thinking right now, in regards to the title:

> Margins are supposed to be used only to space things on the Y axis (bottom/top) and paddings for the X axis (right/left).

But check this out:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 240px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 24px 0 0 0;
}

.item:first-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
      background-image:
      linear-gradient(to bottom,
        white 0%,
        white 100%),
      linear-gradient(to bottom,
        #ccfff5 0%,
        #ccfff5 100%);
    background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: initial;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 12px 0 0 0;
}

.first-button {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="one">
    <h3>This is some title!</h3>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="first-button">Click</button>
      <button class="second-button">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="one">
    <h3>This is some title!</h3>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="first-button">Click</button>
      <button class="second-button">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In order for me to space these buttons out **and not change my markup to have a container for each button**, I must use `margin`. The problem now becomes, tho, assuming we worked on a bigger scale...what if the big container becomes smaller?

Margins, when dealing with absolute values such as `12px`, don't respect the size of the container on any axis and if it becomes smaller, then things start to look very messy since you have overflowing margins everywhere.

What should I use for what?

Comment: you can use media query to change margin when the container become smaller

Comment: From where did you found the quote?

Comment: @YongQuan I mean, sorry, I just thought that if it had the yellow background, it'd be seen as what I currently see as the rule and therefore it's very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where you got that snippet from that margins are for Y axis and padding is for X axis because there are plenty of cases where you would want to change both along both axis's.

The simple answer is margins are what goes around the outside of the border while padding is for what goes inside the border but outside the content.

The box model is a good reference.

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_boxmodel.asp

(Edit: After being downvoted because I guess I'm not being explicit enough)

You should use margin if you're looking to adjust the distance between borders of elements and padding when want to decrease or increase the space between the content and the border.  So if you are looking to maximize space for your content I'd leave padding at near 0px and use the margin to adjust the distance between objects.

Comment: Not sure why you got down-voted but it's a good answer. I'll try to keep reading on the box model but it's hard to know what's right or wrong from it. Not all good things that are made are inherently good from the vendor or maybe the standard is different.